# How to delay rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, redux-offline

//offline.js

```
import { offline } from '@redux-offline/redux-offline';
import offlineConfig from '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/defaults';

const config = params => ({
  ...offlineConfig,
  persistCallback: params.persistCallback
});

export default params => offline(config(params));
```

//App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.store = Reactotron.createStore(
      reducers,
      undefined,
      compose(
        applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
        offline({ persistCallback: this.startApp })
      )
    );
  }

  startApp = () => {
    if (this.store.getState().auth.loggedIn) {
      const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'summmary' })],
      });
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have 2 screens `summary` and `login` where `login` screen will be rendered by default. However I added this logic `this.store.getState().auth.loggedIn` to check that if it's true then dispatch the screen to `summary` but I'm getting `Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The navigation prop is available to the Screen components that are wrapped inside your MainNavigator.

You're trying to use it from your App component which is **outside** of your navigators so it is undefined.

In this case it is recommended to use "Navigating without the navigation prop" approach as described in the documentation:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you don't have the `navigation` object in scope.

Ideally, your `App.js` file should have the `StackNaviator` class itself. So, the first object declared there, will the first screen you'll land to. There you can write the logic of dispatching it to another screen as you have the `navigation` object in scope as well.

Something on the lines of -

Your `App.js`

```
createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
  screen: HomeScreen}
})
```

So, your home screen will be launched first, and the logic you wrote in `App.js` about dispatching an action can move to this `HomeScreen`

Comment: All the `react-navigation` related declaration are defined in `MainNavigator` component